# Cannot Get /auth/google : Passport JS Google Oauth strategy

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-oauth, passport.js, ejs

I am trying to implement the google oauth2 strategy in my application. When I am hitting the route http://localhost:3000/auth/google I am getting : Cannot GET /auth/google. Seems like this route is not getting created. I am using the passport documentation and here is my code:

```
passport.use(
      new GoogleStrategy(
        {
          clientID: googleClientId,
          clientSecret: googleClientSecret,
          callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback",
          passReqToCallback: true,
        },
        function (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
          return done(err, profile);
        }
      )
    );
```

And my authenticate requests are:

```
app.get(
  "/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["email", "profile"] })
);
app.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: "/dashboard",
    failureRedirect: "/users/login",
  })
);
```

I don't know what i am doing wrong. Please help me in fixing this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

const passport = require("passport")

**app.use(passport.initialize())**
use this in your  index.js or whatever you gave name of index file in server.

Comment: i have already used this in app.js file... issue seems to be something else..@MohdFaizan_06

Comment: Could you show me the code where you are hitting auth api. Like in browser .

Comment: I think that the route and the authenticate request can't be the same, try to change app.get("/auth/google", to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Since in my app.js I was using

```
app.use("/users", require("./routes/users.js"));
```

So, the actual route I had to hit was `localhost:3000/users/auth/google`